# JSON schema validation by value

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to validate the value of one field in my JSON with the respect to the other field. It will be clear in the example.

I have a field "interface", that is an "enum": ["01", "02"]
Then I have a field "template", that is an "enum": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"].

Now what I want to achieve is:

IF "interface" is "01", THEN "template" can be: ["01", "02", "03", "04"].

IF "interface" is "02", THEN "template" can be: ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"].

Is that possible to do with JSON schema v4?

Answer (score 1):

The [latest version](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.appendix.B) of the json schema validation spec has explicit support for [if/then/else](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.6) constructs, although the latest draft is not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "oneOf" with 2 definitions.

The first has interface with value 01 (use an enum with only one value) and template with all the possible values (for when interface is 01), again, using enums.

And the 2nd definition for the interface with value 02 and the template with the possible values for when interface is 02.

See these on how to use oneOf:

- https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#oneof
- http://queirozf.com/entries/json-schema-examples